# Ansible to terraform: Creating instances

Tags: ansible, terraform

Im having trouble migrating from ansible to terrafrom when lunching ec2 instances.
With ansible you can define a group of servers in an inventory file

```
[GRAYLOG_SERVERS]
graylog-master ansible_host=1.1.1.1 disk_size=50 instance_type=t2.small
graylog-slave ansible-host=1.1.1.2 disk_size=50 instance_type=t2.small
[GRAYLOG_SERVERS:vars]
var=foo
elb=bla
```

And lunch your instances via the ec2 module example:

```
- name: lunching instance
  ec2:
    aws_access_key: "{{ access_key }}"
    aws_secret_key: "{{ secret_key }}"
    key_name: "{{ ec2_keypair }}"
    group_id: "{{ target_security_groups }}"
    instance_type: "{{ instance_type }}"
    image: "{{ target_ami }}"
    vpc_subnet_id: "{{ instance_subnet_id }}"
    region: "{{ aws_region }}"
    instance_tags: '{"Name":"{{ec2_tag_Name}}","Product":"{{ec2_tag_Product}}","Environment":"{{ec2_tag_Environment}}"}'
    private_ip: "{{ ansible_host }}"
    exact_count: 1
    count_tag: '{"Name":"{{ec2_tag_Name}}","Product":"{{ec2_tag_Product}}","Environment":"{{ec2_tag_Environment}}"}'
    assign_public_ip: no
    wait: true
    volumes:
    - device_name: "{{ device_name }}"
      device_type: "{{ device_type }}"
      volume_size: "{{ disk_size }}"
      delete_on_termination: true
  delegate_to: localhost
  when: ec2_image is defined or ami_id is defined
  register: ec2
```

I can create instances counts based on groups of servers and other options like adding `--limit` per group

Can such operation be duplicated with Terraform ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use [auto scaling groups](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/autoscaling_group.html) and [launch configurations](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/launch_configuration.html)